# Using Bravura Font symbols (Music symbols, Unicode)

Tags: text-object, font

I am trying to display an eighth note in Blender as text using the free Bravura "SMuFL" font. This is what I do:

1. I drag-open a new window in Blender
2. I change that window to "Text Editor"
3. I enter "ECA8" while holding down the OPT key on my Mac (and having "Unicode Hex Input" activated in the keyboard settings)

At this point the symbol of an eighth-note (down stem) should show up, but nothing happens.
The idea is to use "Edit => Text to 3D" (and change the font to "Bravura" in the text settings of the object). But I don't even get that far.

The unicode settings of the Bravura font can be found here:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/w3c/smufl/gh-pages/metadata/glyphnames.json

The symbol I want to use is called "metNote8thDown"

What do I have to do to be able to use that font in Blender?

[image]